# SSAS average calculation for parent / child

Tags: sql, ssas, olap, olap-cube

Having issues getting the average for Parent TotalAverage (getting SUM instead) in SSAS

[image: Example]

Should be 100 in TotalAverage but is the sum 300.

Any suggestions??

I have this already as a calculation:

```
Avg(Descendants([Product V].[Product].CurrentMember.Children),[Measures].[Avg Price])
```

But in this case the children values are not displayed - Item1, Item2, Item3 (100, 100, 100)

Whereas the correct TotalAverage is displayed (100).

I have a manual solution, but this should be a possibility in Visual Studio by standard?:

```
CASE 
Avg([Product V].[Product].CurrentMember.Children,[Measures].[Avg Price])
WHEN NULL THEN [Measures].[Avg Price]
ELSE Avg([Product V].[Product].CurrentMember.Children,[Measures].[Avg Price])
END
```

Comment: Is the 100 for Item1 a sum of the values for Item 1 or an average?  What does the hierarchy look like for Product  V?

Comment: It is an average. The hierarchy is : product category -> product